# viewpage2 imageview click current image open another activity current image show after swipe next image in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-viewpager2

I have image ArrayList. First Activity imageview in viewpager2 and second Activity fullscreen imageview in Viewpager2.

when First Activity Third image click to open Third image in second Activity after swipe right fourth, fifth image show and swipe left second and First image show.

```
  interface ImageDataInterface {
        fun getImage(imageList : ArrayList<Image>)
    }
```

FirstActivity.kt

```
 val adapter = FirstActivityAdapter(this,imageList,this)
            binding.viewPager2First.adapter = adapter
    
     override fun getImage(imageList: ArrayList<Image>) {
            val intent = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("image",imageList)
    
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

FirstActivityAdapter.kt

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val image = imageList.get(position)
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(image.image)
            .into(holder.image)
       
        holder.image.setOnClickListener {
            imageInterface.getProductImage(imageList as ArrayList<Image>)
        }

    }
```

SecondActivity.kt

```
val imageList1 = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Image>("image")
        val adapter = imageList1?.let { SecondActivityAdapter(this, it) }
        binding.viewPager2Second.adapter = adapter
```

In Above code run Successfully but Current image is not show in second Activity, it's show first image and its show one by one but  i have get current image third to show third image after swipe right to fourth and fifth image show, swipe left to second and first image show.